# How to shuffle elements of Mutable list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I wanted to create a `MutableList` of alphabets and then shuffle them and store it in another `MutableList`.

I used `shuffle()` function but it resulted in the original list being shuffled as well which I didn't wanted to happen as I will be using the original list to map it with new shuffled one.

```
fun main(){

    val alphabets = ('A'..'Z').toMutableList()
    
    var shuffAlp = alphabets
    shuffAlp.shuffle()

    println(alphabets)
    println(shuffAlp)
}
```

So I had to create two mutable list and then shuffle one of them

```
val alphabets = ('A'..'Z').toMutableList()
var shuffAlp = ('A'..'Z').toMutableList()
shuffAlp.shuffle()
```

This might be a trivial question but is there any other way where I do not have to create two same list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[shuffle](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffle.html) does shuffle into original list, [shuffled](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffled.html) do and return new list.

And same behavior is for [sort](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort.html) & [sorted](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted.html), [sortBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html) & [sortedBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html), [reverse](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reverse.html) & [asReversed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html):

```kotlin
fun main(){
    val alphabets = ('A'..'Z').toMutableList()
    val shuffAlp = alphabets.shuffled()

    println(alphabets)
    println(shuffAlp)
}
```

Result:

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]
[U, B, A, N, H, R, O, K, X, C, W, E, Q, P, J, Z, L, Y, S, M, I, D, V, F, G, T]
```